# catalog/maven - Demoiselle

Tags: demoiselle

Bom dia, à todos !

Executei o comando demoiselle-worspace, foi gerado a workspace, porém sem o servidor jboss somente o tomcat. Mesmo assim configurei o AS Jboss, mas no ato de escolher o catalog demoiselle não apresenta o mesmo. Instalei o linuxMint 17.1, a JVM instalada é da SUN java 7, meu arquivos source.list está sem deb http://demoiselle.c3sl.ufpr.br universal stable. Qual procedimento devo fazer? instalar o kit jdk 6 da oracle e acrescentar esse arquivo no source.list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welder,

Seguiu as instruções deste material? http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/infra/reference/2.0.0/html/

Para funcionamento correto do Eclipse, precisa ter uma JDK, que pode ser 6 ou 7. No Mint tem opção pela OpenJDK.
A linha  deb http://demoiselle.c3sl.ufpr.br universal stable tem que estar no source.list para poder instalar o pacote do Demoiselle: **demoiselle-2-infra-3**

Caso já tenha as instruções a cima, vc pode enviar o resultado da execução do comando **demoiselle-workspace**.

Comment: Olá Emerson, fiz algumas alterações no SO linuxMint 17.1, por ventura não está constando mais no source.list  o link: http://demoiselle.c3sl.ufpr.br/ vou adicionar o link do source.list e inserir o comando para criação da workspace.

Comment: Funcionou, antes eu tinha baixado a chaves e armazenado em um diretório, exclui as chaves e baixei novamente, gerando a workspace como root não conseguiu acessar o workspace, agora sem o super usuário consegui.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, acho que vou melhorar a documentação para ficar claro que para criação do workspace não deve ser como root.